# Visualizing relationships in log-link/exponential distribution models by placing the linear predictor on the Y axis?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, exponential-distribution, exponential-family, log-linear

I'm visualizing results from a negative binomial regression. I don't want to the graph of Y vs X to look exponential, I want it to look linear. In SPSS, the value provided for the linear predictor is equal the log of model-predicted values of the response variable.

Would it make sense to plot the linear predictor on the vertical axis and values of the independent variable on the horizontal axis to show a linear relationship (vs exponential)?

Comment: Sure. If  you want to see data on the same plot you could apply the link function as a transformation, but it won't have the same expectation as the linear predictor (there may be a noticeable amount of bias in some situations). In some cases it's reasonable to apply a simple bias correction in the transformation if the data so that it would be expected to be close to the linear predictor on average if the model were correct. If I get a moment somewhere suitable to sit with pen and paper I'll look at whether that should be simple for the negative binomial

Comment: Actually a value like $\log(y+0.5)$ might do reasonably well as long as the mean is not too small. There are more sophisticated adjustments that will do better on the asymptotic bias but this would probably be close enough for plotting purposes in many cases.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks so much for your responses. What would the rationale be for taking the log of y+0.5, and what would this be doing? It seems more intuitive to simply take the log of y; doing so appears to visualize the model well.

Comment: 1. Bias: $E(\log(y)) < \log(E(y))$, as already explained above. This suggestion doesn't fix that issue (it's more complicated than that) but does mitigate it somewhat.  2. $\log(0) \to -\infty$ ... what are you doing with $\log(0)$'s?

Comment: @Glen_b There are no 0's predicted, so not a concern here thankfully. I suppose I was wondering why 0.5 specifically would be suggested to correct for bias as opposed to some other value? Does it have to do with the probability of a success or failure in a Bernoulli trial being 0.5?

Comment: It's just a rough compromise between several different things, there's no great art behind it. It performs more or less okay for a number of different parameter values; as I said above there's better adjustments (that specifically take into account at least one of the parameters rather than just using a constant). No, it has nothing to do with 0.5 in a Bernoulli trial. I wanted a suggestion that would fit in a brief comment of a sentence or two and that was the simplest suggestion that I presumed wouldn't require a lot of justification -- not that you should feel dissuaded from asking for some

Comment: The issue with plotting data when you want to look at effects on the log-scale is sometimes you want to be able to plot something *before* you have fitted a model, so ideally you want something that doesn't rely on parameter values or parameter estimates in the transformation. Necessarily that involves compromises.